# Moving from one host to virtual hosts in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I currently just have one non-virtual host and my httpd.conf file is a regular run-of-the-mill file with ordinary modules and stuff. Now I have a need for another host yet it needs to be on the same server. I found apache virtual hosts and have a question about the setup of my config file.

Right now:

```
Listen 80
<IfModule> ........
.....
....
```

My question is, to keep the same settings for each virtual host do I have to copy my current file twice? One inside each virtual host tag? Like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Listen 80
<IfModule> ............
......
......
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
Listen 80
<IfModule> .............
.........
........
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope I'm explaining myself correctly.

Answer (score 0):

No. Those httpd.conf settings are global context (Listen) and scope (LoadModule) and you do not duplicate them in VirtualHosts.

Note that it's a bit more complicated with what can and cannot be set in VHs, and what is inherited.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html for context.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, most of your config file is global. You really just need to put in the virtual config, the bits that are different. There's really two key items:

The DocumentRoot, and ServerName. You might also have different log files, directory index, Aliases, etc. But the two key lines are as below.

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/serverroot
    ServerName name.example.com
```